# Python Selenium waits. Preventing Stale errors when pages are identical

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, webdriverwait

I am tying to scrape a website that loads the identical URL but with an updated store and prices. I am getting stale errors on zipStore1.click() about half of the time. I am also looking for a better solution to time.sleep(10) in-between page loads. I have gone through many possible solutions and none seem to work. Finally, am I using the WebDriverWait methods correctly?

```
for zip in zipCodes:

# opening the webDriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')
driver.implicitly_wait(100)
driver.maximize_window()

#Open product URL
driver.get("https://www.homedepot.com"
           "/p/Everbilt-1-2-in-x-4-ft-x-25-ft-19-Gauge-Steel-Hardware-Cloth-308226EB/205960849")
print("Opened url, setting zip")

# set the zip code
yourStore = WebDriverWait(driver, 10, ignored_exceptions=ignored_exceptions).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='myStore']/a/span")))
yourStore.click()

find_Other_Stores = WebDriverWait(driver, 10, ignored_exceptions=ignored_exceptions).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='myStoreDropdown']/div/div[4]/a/span")))
find_Other_Stores.click()

zipInput = WebDriverWait(driver, 10, ignored_exceptions=ignored_exceptions).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='myStore-formInput']")))
zipInput.send_keys(zip)
zipInput.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

zipStore1 = WebDriverWait(driver, 10, ignored_exceptions=ignored_exceptions).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='myStore-list']/div[1]/div[6]/button/span[2]")))
zipStore1.click()


#this is a temp solution
time.sleep(10)


# select the WebElement that contains the price, and print it
results_D = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='standard-price']/div/div/span[2]")
dollars = results_D.get_attribute("innerHTML")
print(dollars)

results_C = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='standard-price']/div/div/span[3]")
cents = results_C.get_attribute("innerHTML")
print(cents)
total = int(dollars) + (float(cents) / 100)
print(total)

# Close out the webDriver
driver.close()
```

Edit 1: The error is: StaleElementReferenceException

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: StaleElementReferenceException

Comment: That means the DOM is still changing underneath you while you identify the element and then click. Perhaps your 10 second sleep isn't enough? Does it work if you crank that to 30? I bet if you solve that issue the stale element will resolve.